# ACF of MA(q) cuts off after lag q - but isn't it also AR(∞)?

Tags: arima, autocorrelation, autoregressive, moving-average

I struggle with that thought process a bit - intuitively I get why the ACF of an MA(q) would cut off as there's no more dependence for >q.

But if we can express an MA(q) as an AR(∞) - how does that agree with the fact that the ACF of an AR process doesn't cut off?

Furthermore, why does the PACF for an MA(q) not cut off for >q - how are we "bringing back" some of the dependence by excluding extra terms?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine you have some infinite AR. Then in general an infinite set of AR terms, each with its own geometrically-decreasing but never-cut-off-ing ACF won't cut off (of course).

However, we're not dealing with the general case; the question is ... is it possible to make particular ACF values zero with an infinite AR?

Imagine you're free to choose population parameters to solve a problem: could we keep the first $k$ ACF values as is but set the ACF at lag $k+1$ to be $0$? Indeed, it turns out that we can -- it imposes a specific kind of restriction on the parameters. Could we set the ACF at lags $k+1$ and $k+2$ to be $0$? Well, yes, again, we can do that, but now we have an additional restriction on our set of parameters. If we keep going we can set all the later ones to zero.  We end up with the infinite set of AR parameters that corresponds to an invertible MA.

You might like to consider an AR(1) with parameter $\phi_1$. How does its ACF go?
Now consider we have an AR(2) with that $\phi_1$ parameter; what value of $\phi_2$ in an AR(2) would zero out the ACF at lag 2? Given that resulting ACF, can you zero out the third autocorrelation with an AR(3)? ... Now look at an MA(1) which has the same lag-1 autocorrelation and invert it ... what are the first few AR terms?

Your last question seems to be based on some confusion. The higher-lag autocorrelations are 0 but the remaining autocorrelation after you remove the effect of earlier autocorrelations is not 0; in that particular sense there is dependence there.